# How to sent ETH from Parity command line

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, cpp-ethereum, ubuntu, linux

I was wondering if it is possible to send ETH using the parity command line, without opening the browser and going to the address 127.0.0.1:8080. I want to host my Parity instance on a headless machine and so I wouldn't be able to use the Parity browser to get things done. I like Parity, and I've been having trouble getting geth to behave recently, so if it has similar functionality I'd like to learn more about that.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score -1):

Well it would seem that you can do this, via the "JSON-RPC API," which I have no experience with. So at a very beginner level, I can tell you what I have figured out:
1. You need to start Parity with the API features enabled:
*parity --jsonrpc-apis web3,parity,parity_accounts,personal*

2. Next, structure a command for the "personal_sendTransaction" command, which includes the to/from addresses, and an unencrypted password for the "from" account. You can read about the APIs here: https://wiki.parity.io/JSONRPC-personal-module.html#personal_sendtransaction
3. Just for a safe little test to see if you can use the API, just try to list your accounts, or create a dummy account: 
   curl --data '{"method":"personal_listAccounts","params":[],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545

AND

curl --data '{"method":"personal_newAccount","params":["hunter2"],"id":1,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST localhost:8545

I hope this was informative for someone. Thanks!